# HTML Page icon is not showing up in Django

Tags: python, django

This is how I've referenced it.

```
{% load static %}
<link href="{% static 'Assets/img/globe.png' %}" rel="icon" />
```

Comment: Are you running in debug mode, and if not, have you run `collectstatic`? Also, have you set `STATIC_ROOT` in `settings.py`?

Comment: DEBUG is set to True, all my other css in the same folder is working apart from this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a .jpg image and it’s now showing up. Still don’t know why a .png image is not working my head tag because they’re working in the body tag

Comment: Odd, what does the browser inspector show for the .png file? Is it finding it? Status 200 will indicate it's finding the file but not displaying it, 404 will mean it can't find it at all.